# Find $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left({\frac{x^k}{1+x+...+x^k}}\right)^{1+2x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left({\frac{x^k}{1+x+...+x^k}}\right)^{1+2x}=\frac{1}{e^2}$$
I have tried getting something like $(1+1/x)^x$ but don't know how. Also exponeting the limit didn't help.

Comment: In this case transforming to the form $(1+1/A)^{A}$ is going to be more convenient than to the form $e^{ln(A)}$. The former reduces the computation to the computation of a limit of a rational function. The latter will make you have to deal with a logarithm, which is not hard, but if it can be avoided, better to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT $$1+x+...+x^k=\frac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1}$$

Also use the usual trick $f(x)=e^{\ln{f(x)}}$

Answer (score 1):

If $L=\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)^{g(x)} \rightarrow 1^{\infty},$ then $L= \exp[\lim_{x \rightarrow a} [g(x)(f(x)-1].$ Here
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{x^k}{1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^k}\right)^{1+2x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{x^{k+1}-x^{k}}{x^{k+1}-1}\right)^{1+2x}$$
$$\implies \exp \left[\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (1+2x)\left( \frac{x^k-1}{x^{k+1}-1}\right)\right]= \exp \left[\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+2x}{x}\right] =e^2.$$